# Does Zeep support attachments?

Tags: python, soap, attachment, multipart

Does Python SOAP client library [Zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/index.html) support attachments?

I could not really find anything in the [documentation](http://docs.python-zeep.org).

The idea is to send a SOAP request in XML format, with some attached files. I guess the regular way of doing this is a multipart message, which seems to be suppored by requests, upon which Zeep is built.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass Transport class and override the post_xml method to modify the envelope attach multipart files.
I just finihed a silly module (based on this post [How to send Multipart/related requests in Python to SOAP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558812/how-to-send-multipart-related-requests-in-python-to-soap-server)) that does the trick.

https://github.com/ellethee/python-zeep/blob/master/src/zeep/transport_with_attach.py

hope it can help.